# Curl - load multiple addresses from text file

Tags: html, curl, http-headers

I want curl to load addresses from a text file to do head requests.
I'm trying this way:

`curl -I -b cookies.txt -D results.txt -A "Mozilla/5.0 " -K mypage.txt`

Where inside the page.txt I wrote this way:

`url = "http://example.com/cats http://example.com/birds http://example.com/dogs"`

But it's not working. So where it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying every url separately like:

```
url = "http://example.com/cats"
url = "http://example.com/birds"
url = "http://example.com/dogs"
```

It worked when I tried.